# Display the value of selected radio button and checkboxes

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox, datepicker, radio-button

I have a set of radio buttons, checkboxes and a datepicker inside of a form. I want to use JQuery to display the selected options before submitting the form... sort of like a preview before submit page. I don't know why my JQuery is not working. I also have  fields and those display just fine. Just can't get the radio button selection value, checkbox select value or the datepicker select value to show up. Here is my HTML below:

```
<div class="col-12 col-md-6">
     <input type="text" id="f-name" name="full-name" placeholder="Full Name*" onblur="if (this.placeholder == '') {this.placeholder = 'Full Name*';}" onfocus="if (this.placeholder == 'Full Name*') {this.placeholder = '';}">
</div>
 <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
      <span>Date of Request*</span>
      <input type="text" id="request-date" placeholder="Select a Date" class="input-type-date datepicker-here" data-language="en" onblur="if (this.placeholder == '') {this.placeholder = 'Select a Date';}" onfocus="if (this.placeholder == 'Select a Date') {this.placeholder = '';}">
</div>
<div class="col-12 col-md-4">
     <span>Contact Preference*</span>
     <label for="phone">
     <input type="radio" name="contact-pref" value="Phone" id="phone"> Phone
     </label>
     <label for="email">
     <input type="radio" name="contact-pref" value="Email" id="email"> Email
     </label>
</div>
<div class="col-12 col-md-4">
     <label for="spec-st"><input type="checkbox" name="info-pref" id="spec-st" value="Specification Street"> Specification Street</label>
</div>
<div class="col-12 col-md-4">
     <label for="parts-n-kits"><input type="checkbox" name="info-pref" id="parts-n-kits" value="Parts &amp; Kits List"> Parts &amp; Kits List</label>
</div>
```

... Down below in the form in the preview page:

```
<div class="col-12 col-md-5 spacing">
     <h5><strong>Full Name</strong></h5><div id="input1"></div>
</div>
<div class="col-12 col-md-5 spacing">
     <h5><strong>Date of Request</strong></h5><div id="input7"></div>
</div>
<div class="col-12 col-md-5 spacing">
     <h5><strong>Contact Preference</strong></h5><div id="input9"></div>
</div>
<div class="col-12 col-md-5 spacing">
     <h5><strong>Report Preferences</strong></h5><div id="input10"></div>
 </div>
```

Here is the JQuery:

```
$('#f-name').keyup(function() {
    $('#input1').text($(this).val());
});
$('#request-date').click(function() {
    $('#input7').text($(this).val());
});
$("[name='contact-pref']:checked").each(function () {
    $('#input9').text($(this).val());
});
$("[name='info-pref']:checked").each(function () {
    $('#input10').text($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: `$('#input9').text(`…`);` (and `input10`) in an `each` loop will overwrite the inner text repeatedly and leave only the last value in there.

Comment: Well the reason I have them in a .each loop is so they can cycle through all the radio buttons/checkboxes within those name groups and see which is selected/checked and then display the value for selected option. Is this not the correct method? @Xufox

Comment: @Xufox I replaced the .each with .click but that also seems to not work. It isn't on keyup because it is not using keyboard keys to select it. What else could I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$('#f-name').keyup(function() {
    $('#input1').text($(this).val());
});
$('#request-date').change(function() {
    $('#input7').text($(this).val());
});
$("[name='contact-pref']").change(function() {
    $('#input9').text($(this).val());
});
$("[name='info-pref']").change(function() {
    var options=[];
    $("[name='info-pref']:checked").each(function() {
        options.push($(this).val());
    });
    $("#input10").text(options.join(" and "));
});
$(".datepicker-here").datepicker();
```

```html
<link href="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/t1m0n/air-datepicker/master/dist/css/datepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/t1m0n/air-datepicker/master/dist/js/datepicker.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/t1m0n/air-datepicker/master/dist/js/i18n/datepicker.en.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

        
<div class="col-12 col-md-6">
     <input type="text" id="f-name" name="full-name" placeholder="Full Name*" onblur="if (this.placeholder == '') {this.placeholder = 'Full Name*';}" onfocus="if (this.placeholder == 'Full Name*') {this.placeholder = '';}">
</div>
 <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
      <span>Date of Request*</span>
      <input type="text" data-language='en' id="request-date" placeholder="Select a Date" class="input-type-date datepicker-here" data-language="en" onblur="if (this.placeholder == '') {this.placeholder = 'Select a Date';}" onfocus="if (this.placeholder == 'Select a Date') {this.placeholder = '';}">
</div>
<div class="col-12 col-md-4">
     <span>Contact Preference*</span>
     <label for="phone">
     <input type="radio" name="contact-pref" value="Phone" id="phone"> Phone
     </label>
     <label for="email">
     <input type="radio" name="contact-pref" value="Email" id="email"> Email
     </label>
</div>
<div class="col-12 col-md-4">
     <label for="spec-st"><input type="checkbox" name="info-pref" id="spec-st" value="Specification Street"> Specification Street</label>
</div>
<div class="col-12 col-md-4">
     <label for="parts-n-kits"><input type="checkbox" name="info-pref" id="parts-n-kits" value="Parts &amp; Kits List"> Parts &amp; Kits List</label>
</div>
<div class="col-12 col-md-5 spacing">
     <h5><strong>Full Name</strong></h5><div id="input1"></div>
</div>
<div class="col-12 col-md-5 spacing">
     <h5><strong>Date of Request</strong></h5><div id="input7"></div>
</div>
<div class="col-12 col-md-5 spacing">
     <h5><strong>Contact Preference</strong></h5><div id="input9"></div>
</div>
<div class="col-12 col-md-5 spacing">
     <h5><strong>Report Preferences</strong></h5><div id="input10"></div>
 </div>
<input type='text' class="datepicker-here" data-position="right top" />
```

Comment: OMG This is amazing! The only thing that is not working is the datepicker. I do have a plugin to make the datepicker. This is the plugin but I don't see how that should conflict with the value once a date is selected. http://t1m0n.name/air-datepicker/docs/ @MBJH

Comment: If it is correct please consider ticking it ;) @AriesAzad

Comment: I marked it correct. Do you have a solution for the datepicker value to be displayed? That is the only one that is not working.